# Execute createShortcut in a Squirrel event, in an Electron app

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, electron

I'm trying to create shortcuts for my Electron app when I install it or update it, however I am having some trouble executing the command that is meant to create the shortcut. 
By default Electron apps are "SquirrelAware", therefore I have to specify where i would like to create shortcuts.

My question is in relation to the accepted answer to this question.

[Handle Squirrel's event on an Electron app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105150/handle-squirrels-event-on-an-electron-app/30782879#30782879)

I have tried to use the `exec` module and the `child_process` module, however both did not seem to work. I am now currently attempting (and failing) to launch PowerShell and run a script in there that will create shortcuts on my Start Menu and Desktop, however I feel this is rather long and that there must be an easier way.

Here is my current attempt using the child_process module and PowerShell:

```
 var spawn = require('child_process').spawn, child;
 child = spawn("C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",["C:\\ElectronSquirrelDemo\\AddAppShortcuts.ps1 -SourceExe "+ executionPath] );
                child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
                    console.log("PowerShell Data: " + data);
                });
                child.stdout.on('data', function(data){
                    console.log("PowerShell Error: " + data);
                });
                child.stdout.on('exit', function(){
                   console.log('PowerShell script finished'); 
                });
```

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It took me awhile to understand how to do this myself. The Squirrel.Windows Update.exe has the ability to create shortcuts to your app for you. I wrote a blog post called [Creating a Windows Distribution of an Electron App using Squirrel](http://www.mylifeforthecode.com/creating-a-windows-distribution-of-an-electron-app-using-squirrel/) and in it I have Squirrel create the shortcuts for me. If you want to go this route, this is simplified version of how to have Squirrel create the shortcuts for you:

```
var cp = require('child_process');    
var updateDotExe = path.resolve(path.dirname(process.execPath), '..', 'update.exe');
var target = path.basename(process.execPath);
var child = cp.spawn(updateDotExe, ["--createShortcut", target], { detached: true });
child.on('close', function(code) {
    app.quit();
});
```

You need to hack the electron executable using Resource Hacker, rcedit, or another application to change the ProductName and Icon resources. You'll want to call the above code on both the install and updated Squirrel events.

Comment: This was very similar to an earlier attempt of mine, however i think my file may have been playing up, as it was logging stuff in random orders. So i deleted the file and created a new one and it worked with your answer. I also checked out your blog, there are some very helpful Electron tips and tricks there. Thanks!

Comment: @Shawn Rakowski, the link above doesn't work any more, can you help update? Actually, I am trying to execute some other commands after finishing install of app with this package: https://github.com/automation-stack/electron-sudo, as I need to create a windows task scheduler for my app. However, it doesn't work. I wonder if during the squirrel events happens, it doesn't allow other tools like node.js or electron-sudo to run a child process. If you have some idea, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Ng2-Fun my hosting service suspended my blog for some random query overrun. I haven't had a chance to get things resolved, but will try to early next week... Sorry I don't have a good idea on what your problem may be :(

Comment: @Shawn Rakowski - I already solved my issue. It can execute other commands. I didn't put the code in the right position in the past.